# Why is the A220 cockpit seat question being considered a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53643/1467) got voted as a duplicate of [this other question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12439/1467).

Both before and after closure [it got edited](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/53643/revisions) to avoid being a duplicate.

Despite the edits, [people voted to keep it closed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/34166).

I am obviously biased, having answered it (and that's why I have not used my reopen vote, being a mod it would count for 5), but I can't see it being a duplicate in its current form. Can someone explain why they think it is a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't vote, but the accepted answer on the older post states two reasons. Reason number 2 answers the question:

> [...] moving the crotch strap of the harness closer to the body of the pilot.

A cutout is also present on the A**3**20 as that answer shows.

Basically reason 2 answers the why (function) question. It can be edited however to focus on the decision-making (not the function). But that will also require revising the tone of the new answer.

Comment: FWIW, this is exactly why I voted to leave it closed